# How to add attribute to every file in VOB at element (not version) level

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to add an attribute to the element for every file in a given VOB, and I can't find the syntax to avoid having the attribute added to the version instead of the element.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
cleartool find . -exec "cleartool mkattr Exception \\\"NEW_VAL\\\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

I always get output to the effect of

```
Created attribute "Exception" on ".\bigrdj6000\bigrdj6000.fmb@@\main\4".
```

I've tried lots of combinations of -nxn, -all and -element on the find command, but I just can't seem to get rid of the @@\main\4

Can somebody please put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cleartool find . -exec "cleartool mkattr Exception \\\"NEW_VAL\\\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%@@\""
                                                                                   ^^
                                                                                    |
                                                  (final '@@' to reference an element)
```

The problem is that `\"%CLEARCASE_PN%\"` represents a file within a view, meaning the *version* of that file as selected by the config spec of that view.

However, `\"%CLEARCASE_PN%@@\"` should represent the *element* of that file.

This is compliant with the [`mkattr` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattr.htm):

```
cmd-context mkattr RESPONSIBLE \"Anne\" hello.c@@
Created attribute "RESPONSIBLE" on "hello.c@@".
```