# Allow everyone to lock/unlock a ClearCase branch

Tags: clearcase

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280685/toward-an-ideal-workflow-with-clearcase-and-git) I concluded to use the lock/unlock mechanism of ClearCase to work efficiently with Git.

Unfortunately I realized only a branch owner can perform a lock/unlock operation

```
$ ct lock brtype:main-br-foo
cleartool: Error: No permission to perform operation "lock".
cleartool: Error: Must be one of: object owner, VOB owner, member of ClearCase group
cleartool: Error: Unable to lock branch type "main-br-foo".
```

Is there any solution to allow any member of a VOB to do lock/unlock ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use a pre-op trigger on the checkout operation, which would:

- prevent the checkout if an attribute (named 'lock') is set on the file (set using [`cleartool mkattr` as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16355013/6309))
- allow the checkout to proceed if the attribute is not there.

[Removing an attribute](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmattr.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-53) can be done by anyone with the same group member as the object having the attribute, so this model is less constrained than the one using `cleartool lock`.

You can complete it with a post-op trigger on checkin, which would remove automatically the attribute 'lock' if found on the element.

To set an attribute to a branch you do:

```
cleartool mkattype -nc islocked  # Should be done once

cleartool mkattr islocked \"true\" brtype:branch_name
```

Comment: @coin no, you don't need to do a mkattr on all: only on the one you want to lock: replace your cleartool lock by a script which does the mkattr only on the file to be locked reserved.

Comment: @coin Mastership permission has nothing to do with locking, and everything with multi-site multisynch operations.

Comment: @coin you can apply the solution to a branch as well: you can add an attribute to a branch. Even to a vob.

Comment: @coin the syntax seems a bit off: the brtype should be at the end as in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/archives/cciug/hypermail/0012/0477.html: `cleartool mkattr abc \"bar\" brtype:solution-abc `

Comment: Still not working :( `$ ct mkattr locked \"true\" brtype:br-foo
cleartool: Error: attribute type "locked" not found in VOB "\my_vob" and no global type definition can be found.
cleartool: Error: Unable to create attribute "locked" on "br-foo".`

Comment: @coin yes, you need to define the attribute *type* first (one-time operation), before instanciating that type as attribute over files, branches or vob: `cleartool mkattype`: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattype.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-33

Comment: @coin great, don't hesitate to add the triggers as well once it will work.